# how to extract key value pairs from text file with key in first line and consecutive vertically aligned values?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, text, dictionary-comprehension

I have a text file which was directly copied from an Excel in the following format:

```
Sr No,Employee ID,Name,Department,DOJ,1-Apr,2-Apr,3-Apr,4-Apr,5-Apr...31-Apr
1,ID001,Jason Smith,IT,01-Sep-22,WO,WO,P,P,P....
2,ID002,Pearson Smith,IT,01-Sep-22,WO,P,P,WO,P....
```

The symbols (WO,P) are attendance records for each day day.

I am trying to make a list of dictionary out of this. The keys for the same would be the first line in text file and the consecutive data in each line after that should be appended to that key.

It should look something like this:

```
line2_dictionary = {'Sr No':'1','Employee ID':'ID001','Name':'Jason Simith','Department':'IT','DOJ':'01-Sep-22','1-Apr':'WO','2-Apr':'P','3-Apr':'P'....}
```

Each line of data will be a new dictionary in above format which will be combine together to form a list.

I tried the approach of a dictionary comprehension but I am very new to python and hence need a little help. The below method is writing the same value('WO') in each key.

```py
input_data = []
with open(r'file_path','r') as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        input_data.append(line.strip('\n'))
    
attendance_dict = {key: None for key in input_data[0].split(',')}
for line in input_data[1:-1]:
        attendance_dict = {k:v for k in attendance_dict for v in line.split(",")}
```

Answer (score 0):

Luckily there is no need to assign the values to a dictionary field by field:

```
import csv

input_file = csv.DictReader(open("attendance.csv"))

for row in input_file:
    print(row)
```

The result looks like this:

```
{'Sr No': '1', 'Employee ID': 'ID001', 'Name': 'Jason Smith', 'Department': 'IT', 'DOJ': '01-Sep-22', '1-Apr': 'WO', '2-Apr': 'WO', '3-Apr': 'P', '4-Apr': 'P', '5-Apr': 'P'}
{'Sr No': '2', 'Employee ID': 'ID002', 'Name': 'Pearson Smith', 'Department': 'IT', 'DOJ': '01-Sep-22', '1-Apr': 'WO', '2-Apr': 'P', '3-Apr': 'P', '4-Apr': 'WO', '5-Apr': 'P'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
# to read the file into a dataframe:
df = pd.read_csv('your_data.csv')

# to put the dataframe into a list-of-dicts:
out = df.to_dict(orient="records")
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    {
        "Sr No": 1,
        "Employee ID": "ID001",
        "Name": "Jason Smith",
        "Department": "IT",
        "DOJ": "01-Sep-22",
        "1-Apr": "WO",
        "2-Apr": "WO",
        "3-Apr": "P",
        "4-Apr": "P",
        "5-Apr": "P",
    },
    {
        "Sr No": 2,
        "Employee ID": "ID002",
        "Name": "Pearson Smith",
        "Department": "IT",
        "DOJ": "01-Sep-22",
        "1-Apr": "WO",
        "2-Apr": "P",
        "3-Apr": "P",
        "4-Apr": "WO",
        "5-Apr": "P",
    },
]
```

---

Initial `df`:

```
   Sr No Employee ID           Name Department        DOJ 1-Apr 2-Apr 3-Apr 4-Apr 5-Apr
0      1       ID001    Jason Smith         IT  01-Sep-22    WO    WO     P     P     P
1      2       ID002  Pearson Smith         IT  01-Sep-22    WO     P     P    WO     P
```